# ADDING white background to an image?

Tags: beamer, graphics, color

I'm new to beamer and am trying to make a presentation. When inserting an image, the output is satisfactory, except when I try to insert a `.pdf`! The white layer in the image disappears. Initially, the image was a `.ps`, so I used `ps2pdf14` to convert it to `.pdf` and then `pdfcrop` to add the amount of white border I desire. I can convert the `.pdf` to `.png` and it works fine, but the quality isn't good enough for big pictures. Is there a way to restore the white layer when inserting the `.pdf` image? I apologize if this is a trivial question, or if I've simply over looked something.

Here's an example code to illustrate the problem

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames,mathserif,serif]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{47,94,142}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=myblue}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\title{Sample Title}
\author{\large{Me}}
\institute{\small{University}}
\date{\small{Today's Date}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Sample Title}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3in]{1.pdf} %why isn't white space appearing?
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip:  You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863); also, if you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by whitespace (perhaps since we don't have `1.pdf`). For example, do you have an image of size (say) `2in` by `3in` and you want it to have space around it, actually setting to a size of (say) `3in` by `4in`?

Comment: currently, the .pdf has black text, but the background matches my slide when it should have a white background. yes, I believe that is what I want, Werner. I used the command: pdfcrop --margins 5 sample.pdf sample.pdf to add a small amount of whitespace around the image. I want the image to look like the pdfcropped one. converting to .png works fine, but the .pdf version doesn't

Comment: pdf background is transparent, not white. You can force a white background including it into a colorbox. Something like `\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics{1.pdf}}`.

Comment: ah that fixed it! thank you so much for all your help! :)

Answer (score 22):

`pdf` images has a transparent background, so even with a border, when you include them over a colored background the"white border" disappears. The easiest solution would be to include your figure into a white box with `\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics{your-pdf-figure}}`. This way figure's background and border are white.

Update: Missing graphic example for the original answer and some rotating examples for lalebarde's comment.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames,mathserif,serif]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{47,94,142}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=myblue}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Sample Title}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{1842.pdf} %why isn't white space appearing?
\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics{1842.pdf}}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Sample Title}
\begin{center}
\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[angle=90]{1842.pdf}} 
\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[angle=30]{1842.pdf}}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Sample Title}
\begin{center}
\rotatebox{30}{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics{1842.pdf}}} 
\rotatebox{-60}{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics{1842.pdf}}} 
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Note: you can get 1842.pdf sources from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182700/1952)

Comment: If the includegraphics includes a rotation with the angle parameter, it does not work: the part let void by the rotation is still transparent.

Comment: @lalebarde I'm not sure to understand your comment. Do you want that the figure's border also rotates?

Comment: @lalebarde After reading again your comment, I think you want a `rotatebox` instead of `angle` inside `\includegraphics`. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Perfect, works also without `beamer` class.